# Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be invertible such that $A$ and $A^{-1}$ have integer entries. Prove that $\det(A)\in\{-1,1\}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be invertible such that $A$ and $A^{-1}$ have integer entries. Prove that $\det(A)\in\{-1,1\}$.

**My work:**

$\det(I)=\det(AA^{-1})=(-1)^n\det(AA^{-1})=(-1)^n\det(A)\det(A^{-1}).$

I'm stuck here. Can someone help me?

Comment: First piece of help: A^-1 gives the wrong output; you want A^{-1}.

Comment: Second piece of help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)#Inverse_of_a_matrix

Answer (score 5):

$det(A)$ and $det(A^{-1})$ are integers, $det(AA^{-1})=1=det(A)det(A^{-1})$ and an integer is invertible for the multiplication if and only if it is equal to $1$ or $-1$.

Comment: It would be clearer to say *the multiplicative inverse of an integer is again and integer iff ...*

Comment: I dont have very clear the part "an integer is invertible for the multiplication if and only if it is equal to $1$ or $−1$" for example, let $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ then $a$ is invertible if $a=1$?

Comment: if a is 1 or -1